# add random noise and random NA in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to add random NA and random noise in the data

```
    exp_TSPAN6  exp_TNMD    exp_DPM1    exp_SCYL3   exp_C1orf112
0   7.951917    3.524705    12.043700   7.605068    8.214067
1   8.079243    9.545859    5.6445321   8.509788    6.853905
2   11.335783   12.45859    12.254986   6.617365    8.196391
```

**Example Output**

```
    exp_TSPAN6  exp_TNMD    exp_DPM1    exp_SCYL3   exp_C1orf112
0   8.951917    4.524705    11.043700   7.605068    8.214067
1   8.079243    NA          NA          8.509788    6.853905
2   11.335783   NA          12.254986   6.617365    9.196391
```

I have tried the following code to add NA, but I could not add random noise

```
for col in data.columns:
data.loc[data.sample(frac=0.1).index, col] = pd.np.nan
```

Comment: What kind of random noise do you want to add?

Comment: @DaniMesejo random gaussian noise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try what is suggested here: [Adding gaussian noise to a dataset of floating points and save it (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093073/adding-gaussian-noise-to-a-dataset-of-floating-points-and-save-it-python?rq=1)

1. Load the data into a pandas dataframe clean_signal = pd.read_csv("data_file_name")
2. Use numpy to generate Gaussian noise with the same dimension as the dataset.
3. Add gaussian noise to the clean signal with signal = clean_signal + noise